# How to dynamically fetch value using cts:seach in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

My Database is having "n" number of documents and i need to search for document dynamically using the elements and value i am providing. I am explaining it below-

Sample documents in my database-

```
document1-
<root>
    <id1>12345</id1>
    <value>Country</value>
    <node1>somevalue</node1>
    <node2>somevalue</node2>
    <node3>somevalue</node3>
    <node4>somevalue</node4>
    .......................
</root>

document2-
<root>
    <id2>34567</id2>
    <value>Fruits</value>
    <node1>somevalue</node1>
    <node2>somevalue</node2>
    <node3>somevalue</node3>
    <node4>somevalue</node4>
    .......................
</root>
```

I need to give input parameters as Rest End Point to perform my operation and the input to rest xml document is as below-

```
INPUT XML-

<root>
 <id>id1</id>
 <idvalue>12345</idvalue>

 .......................
</root>
```

Output i need is shown in example-

Example- **Search for all the documents from the database which is having Id=Id1 and it's value=12345**

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can explore Query By Example (QBE) of MarkLogic. For more details go to URL https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/qbe

Answer (score 0):

XPath can extract the input values for constructing a cts.elementValueQuery().

Something similar to the following should work in SJS:

```
cts.search(cts.elementValueQuery(
    xs.QName(fn.string(input.xpath('/root/id'))),
    fn.string(input.xpath('/root/idvalue'))
    ))
```

Or similar to the following in XQuery:

```
cts:search(fn:collection(), cts:element-value-query(
    xs:QName(fn:string($input/root/id)),
    fn:string($input/root/idvalue)
    ))
```

For more information, see http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementValueQuery

Hoping that helps,